# Как сделать кнопку "Поделиться" в приложении Python kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, share, kivymd

Делаю приложение для андроид. И мне нужно сделать кнопку для отправки например содержимого текстового поля в воцап или телеграм. Нагуглил как отправлять сообщения, но там сразу прописываеш кому и куда отправлять. А вот можно как нибудь сделать чтобы сначала давался выбор через что отправить и кому? По типу как во многих приложениях кнопка поделиться сначала выводит список (смс, воцап, телеграм, емэйл и т.д.)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63322944/how-to-use-share-button-to-share-content-of-my-app